# nest js this.instance.use is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I studying serverless nest.js with aws lambda

When I run serverless offline and send the request, an error occurred.

```
[Nest] 11048   - 2021. 07. 14. 오후 7:02:11   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 11048   - 2021. 07. 14. 오후 7:02:11   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +16ms
[Nest] 11048   - 2021. 07. 14. 오후 7:02:11   [ExceptionHandler] this.instance.use is not a function +3ms
TypeError: this.instance.use is not a function
    at ExpressAdapter.use (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\adapters\http-adapter.js:20:30)
    at NestApplication.use (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-application.js:140:26)
    at C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:127:40
    at Function.run (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\errors\exceptions-zone.js:9:13)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:126:46)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:168:54)
    at bootstrapServer (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\.build\src\lambda.js:16:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async handler (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\.build\src\lambda.js:23:20)
    at async InProcessRunner.run (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\handler-runner\in-process-runner\InProcessRunner.js:211:24)
    at async LambdaFunction.runHandler (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\lambda\LambdaFunction.js:355:20)
    at async hapiHandler (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\serverless-offline\dist\events\http\HttpServer.js:601:18)
    at async module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:45:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:312:32)
    at async Request._execute (C:\study\nestjs-practice\serverless-nestjs\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:221:9)
```

How can I fix it?

Except for the lambda.ts and serverless.yml files, the settings are the same as when the nest.js project was created.

I'll post the code, please let me know if you know a solution

**lambda.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Handler, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { eventContext } from 'aws-serverless-express/middleware';
import { createServer, proxy } from 'aws-serverless-express';

const binaryMimeTypes: string[] = [];

let cachedServer: Server;

async function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Server> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const expressApp = express();
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(
      AppModule,
      new ExpressAdapter(express),
    );
    nestApp.use(eventContext);
    await nestApp.init();
    cachedServer = createServer(expressApp, undefined, binaryMimeTypes);
  }
  return cachedServer;
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service:
  name: serverless-nestjs

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
  main: # The name of the lambda function
    # The module 'handler' is exported in the file 'src/lambda'
    handler: src/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{any+}
```